# Firefox 28 Installation issue?

Tags: firefox

I have facing to install Firefox 28 in windows 7 OS.
In my project need to install this version to test some automation testing functionalities. I am getting this error message when after installation and try to open Firefox

### "Failed to read the configuration file. Please contact your system administrator."

Please check attached image. Anyone can tell me suggestions to use this Firefox browser
[image]

Comment: uninstall. remove the firefox folder and install again. hope this helps.      Firefox folder location: (32 bit Windows) "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\"
(64 bit Windows) "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\"

Comment: Hi bro, got it.... Now Firefox is working fine in machine. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had that problem as well and fix it by this

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/909867

Comment: Hi Allegon, Thank you so much... Now issue is resolved